# Как открыть xml документ, сохраненный из MSWord?

Tags: php, xml

Есть XML Документ, который был сохранен из MSWord

Пробую открыть его вот так:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('doc.xml');
print_r($xml);
```

Но получаю на выходе пустой объект.
Открываю этот файл в браузере, читает нормально, а php почему то разобрать не может.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Искал библиотеки, которые могли бы напрямую средствами php создать водовский файл doc docx, нашел библиотеку phpword, но, поразбиравшись, понял, что она достаточно кривая и часть функций реализовать нельзя, например, она плохо поддерживает позиционирование элементов на странице (где в мсворд я могу перетащить элемент гуда угодно, библиотека этого сделать не позволяет это как пример)

Увидел что MSWord может прекрасно экспортировать файл в xml формате, а потом так же и открывать его как обычный документ формата docx.

И раз php тоже отлично дружит с XML задача была практически решена.

Пока я просто не попытался открыть этот файл средствами php

Может быть есть способ все таки загрузить этот файл и обработать как xml объект?

Или есть какая то другая библиотка для работы с word в php, которая может больше чем phpword
Открыл docx файл с помощью архиватора на компьютере, и нашел xml файлы, вот их php читает.

Но непонятно, как этот файл таким же образом открыть на сервере, достать нужный файл, а после всех манипуляций запаковать все обратно.

Вот на скрине пример, файл я извлек с помощью архиватора, и открыл через

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('document.xml');
print_r($xml);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно возвращает `simplexml_load_file`? Что выводит `var_dump($xml)`?

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите сделать визуальный редактор word-документов на пхп? Ибо иначе не ясно,  при чем тут ремарка про позиционирование элементов на странице.

Comment: Вы получили распарсенный XML. Дальше вызывайте методы SimpleXML для работы с ним. А `print_r($xml);` это из серии "какой на вкус красный цвет?"

Comment: Нет, мне не нужен визуальный редактор, из базы извлекаются массивы с текстом.
Этот текст мне нужно вставить в определенную область документа.

По определенному шаблону, текст, картинка, текст, водяной знак.

Самое самым простым решениям было бы, взять готовый шаблон word, и в нужные области вставить мою информацию, с переносами строк с картинками. и сохранить его. Так вот это можно было бы сделать с xml файлом.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov мне кажется я получил пустой как мне получить весь массив? чтобы знать к чему обращаться? методы xml я бы мог использовать будет у меня перед глазами массив, например мне его нужно перебрать, посчитать, изключить и тд

Comment: https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html вот это вам не поможет случаем в вашей задаче?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov дополнил вопрос, последний  абзац и срин, пример того когда xml окрылся и я вижу то что мне нужно для дальнейшей работы.

но выше описал процесс получения такого файла, я извлек его с помощью архиватора, положил вручную папку и потом только смог обработать в php,  но непонятно как теперь это все вложить обратно

Comment: Какой массив? Нет никакого массива. `simplexml_load_file` возвращает **объект**. Для манипуляции этим объектом используются его методы

Comment: в ворде вообще есть такие штуки как Content Controls, которые в целом удобны для подобного. поищите кто умеет с ними работать. Можно поименовать абзацы текста, картинки и т.п. потом получать к ним доступ по id и менять содержимое.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, да но мне надо увидеть этот объект чтобы было с чем работать. в последнем случае я его увидел, а вот когда попытался открыть xml сохраненный с помощью word, увидел пустой объект. И по скорости ответа от сервера было понятно что 3мегабайтный файл не был обработан. Зато  в последнем случае, сервере призадумался прежде чем ответить

Comment: в последнем случае у вас браузер призадумался, чтобы прорисовать эту портянку текста, а не сервер

Comment: @teran, спасибо, то что надо